# Passing a list from bind

Tags: python, function, tkinter

Early stages of learning python and I'm stuck at a problem.  I am building a dice game.  I'm looking to pass the value of dice[0] to the holdDie1 function.  The label I created accurately shows the correct value of dice[0], but when I call the function with bind to assign it to another list, I get an error:

line 75, in holdDie1 
keep[0] = dice[0]
TypeError: 'Event' object does not support indexing

```
from tkinter import *
import random

global dice, keep
dice = [1,2,3,4,5]
keep = [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]

def holdDie1(dice):
    x = die1.cget("bg")
    if x == "white":
        die1.configure(bg="coral")
        keep[0] = dice[0]
    else:
        die1.configure(bg="white")
        keep[0] = -1


window = Tk()
window.title("Dice")
window.configure(background="white")

die1 = Label(window, bg="white", text = dice[0], width=6, borderwidth=1, font="none 12 bold", relief="solid")
die1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=6)
die1.bind("<Button-1>", holdDie1)
```

Comment: There is not enough code here to work on the problem. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: All functions that you call with `bind` need the first argument to be "event". Also, you don't need the "dice" argument. So change your first line to this: `def holdDie1(event):`

Comment: Mike, should be better now.  Click on the box of 1.